# How to use the value of a return statement in a different method?

Tags: variables, methods, printing, return, call

I recently started codeing java, so this question might be a little, well, stupid, but i created a small program that averages 5 numbers. I know the program is very over complicated, i have just been trying out some of the new things i've learned.My problem is i would like to get the variable "Answer" up in my main program. I dont want to change around the program if i dont have to.I have returned the value in the average method, and set this answer to the variable Answer, but how can i use System.out.print(Answer) or print the return. Heres the code! Sorry if its not in a code block, i indented 4 spaces, but it doesnt say anything.

```
package Tests;
import java.util.*;
public class average_Test {
static double Total=0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp;
    int count[]={5,1,2,3,4};
    for(int x:count){
    System.out.print("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
    temp=scan.nextInt();
    average(temp);

    }



}
public static double average(int n){

    for(int c=0;c<1;c++){
        Total+=n;
    }
    double average=Total/5;
    System.out.println(average);
    double Answer = Total/5;
    return Total/5;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable binding, or print result of function:

```
double a = average(temp);
System.out.println(a);
```

or:

```
System.out.println(average(temp));
```

At the end it will look like this:

```
double result = 0;
System.out.print("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
for (int x : count) {
    temp = scan.nextInt();
    result = average(temp);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

P.S. code looks weird, consider implementing `double average(int[] numbers)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Yes, my code does look a little weird as i was testing out somethings, and i am a complete noob at java. I rewrote my program and now its working fine after implementing your code                                                                                    double a = average(temp);
    System.out.println(a);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Yes, my code does look a little weird as i was testing out somethings, and i am a complete noob at java. I rewrote my program and now its working fine after implementing your code. So basically to get the return in the main statement you need to set "average(temp)" to a variable in main, then you can just call one or the other. Thanks!